# What is the physical meaning of a pure imaginary force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, complex-numbers, rigid-body-dynamics, time-reversal-symmetry, gyroscopes

I am reading an article [(this)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.115.104302) and the equations result in an inertial force $F_g$ (which I understand as a fictitious force (?)) that is purely imaginary. The system consists of a gyroscope fixed to the floor and attached to a mass (in a lattice of identical masses-gyroscopes) through which a wave passes that would cause a rotational movement on the gyroscope (as detailed below). I understand that due to the nutation of the gyroscope the mass can change its coordinate in z, but I do not understand the physical meaning that it is purely imaginary. As the author details at the end, this indicates *"This imaginary nature of the gyroscopic inertial effect indicates directional phase shifts between two independent directions of the tip displacements, which breaks time-reversal symmetry"*, but I do not understand it at all.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The physical force is not imaginary, it is given by the real part of the expression. That expression is not pure imaginary because each component of ${\bf U}_{\rm tip}$ is itself a complex number here. So its real part (which is the force) will not be zero. The presence of $i$ here is telling you that the oscillations of the force are a quarter-cycle out of phase with the oscillations of the velocity.

This whole calculation is an example of the use of complex numbers to analyze linear sets of equations. It is a method that is particularly helpful when oscillation is involved, because the function $e^{i \omega t}$ is easier to work with than combinations of $\cos(\omega t)$ and $\sin(\omega t)$.

In general if one has a physical quantity $x$ satisfying some equation $\hat{D} x = 0$ then one can introduce a complex number $z$ satisfying $\hat{D} z = 0$, where $\hat{D}$ is some bunch of algebraic operations and differential operations, all real-valued. But for a complex number to be zero, both its real and imaginary parts are zero, so the real part of $z$ here satisfies the same equation as $x$. The method consists in solving $\hat{D} z = 0$ to obtain $z$, and then you finish by asserting $x = {\rm Re}[z]$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was assuming that U was pure real, and forgetting that in (S12) we had defined it as complex.